# Как пишется в новых версиях php массив

Tags: php, yii2

Чисто случайно в коде прописал когда был мозговой штурм и заработало, но как это называется незнаю чтобы даже загуглить.

На хостинге timeweb всё отрабатывает с версией php 7.4 , а вот на openserv с такой же версией не хочет, ругается что этот способ устарел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код в контреллере

```
if ($bloggers_model->load($this->request->post()) && $bloggers_model->save())
        {
            // загрузка доп данных для платформ
            foreach ($platforms_db as $platform) 
            {
                $model_data_platforms {$platform['id']} = new DataPlatformsForm();

                //if (!empty($this->request->post('url_'.$platform['id'])))
                //{
                    $model_data_platforms {$platform['id']}->url = $this->request->post('url_'.$platform['id']);
                    $model_data_platforms {$platform['id']}->id_platform = $this->request->post('platform_id_'.$this->request->post('platform_id_'.$platform['id']));
                    $model_data_platforms {$platform['id']}->subscribers = $this->request->post('subscribers_'.$this->request->post('platform_id_'.$platform['id']));
                    $model_data_platforms {$platform['id']}->coverage = $this->request->post('coverage_'.$this->request->post('platform_id_'.$platform['id']));
                    $model_data_platforms {$platform['id']}->integration_cost = $this->request->post('integration_cost_'.$this->request->post('platform_id_'.$platform['id']));
                    //$model_data_platforms {$platform['id']}->cpm = $this->request->post('cpm_'.$this->request->post('platform_id_'.$platform['id']));
                    //$model_data_platforms {$platform['id']}->cpv = $this->request->post('cpv_'.$this->request->post('platform_id_'.$platform['id']));
                    $model_data_platforms {$platform['id']}->audience_gender = $this->request->post('audience_gender_'.$this->request->post('platform_id_'.$platform['id']));
                    $model_data_platforms {$platform['id']}->involvement = $this->request->post('involvement_'.$this->request->post('platform_id_'.$platform['id']));
                    $model_data_platforms {$platform['id']}->involvement_promotional_post = $this->request->post('involvement_promotional_post_'.$this->request->post('platform_id_'.$platform['id']));

                    $model_data_platforms {$platform['id']}->create_user = Yii::$app->user->identity->username; // пользователь который добавил
                    $model_data_platforms {$platform['id']}->create_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // дата добавления
                    $model_data_platforms {$platform['id']}->id_blogger = $bloggers_model->id; // id блогера
                    $model_data_platforms {$platform['id']}->save();
                //}
            }

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $bloggers_model->id]);
        }
    } else {
        $bloggers_model->loadDefaultValues();
    }
```

Как переписать, для новых версия php ?
И как это назвать, чтобы гуглить?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59158548/9210255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В массивах обращение к элементу происходит через квадратные скобки, а не фигурные. Соответственно все `array{... }` надо заменить на `array [... ]`